# Why does my dictionary doesn't get updated outside of the function? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I can't understand why my dictionary is changing once it has came out of the function. Consider:

```
my_dct = {"A" : 0,
        "B" : 1,
        "C" : 4,
        "D" : 0,
        "E" : 0,
        "Z" : 9,
        "F" : 0,
        "G" : 3,
       }

def remove_0(dct):
    dct = {key:val for key, val in dct.items() if val != 0}
    print(dct)
    return dct

print(my_dct)
remove_0(my_dct)
print(my_dct)
```

This code outputs:

```
{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 4, 'D': 0, 'E': 0, 'Z': 9, 'F': 0, 'G': 3}
{'B': 1, 'C': 4, 'Z': 9, 'G': 3}
{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 4, 'D': 0, 'E': 0, 'Z': 9, 'F': 0, 'G': 3}
```

But shouldn't it output:

```
{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 4, 'D': 0, 'E': 0, 'Z': 9, 'F': 0, 'G': 3}
{'B': 1, 'C': 4, 'Z': 9, 'G': 3}
{'B': 1, 'C': 4, 'Z': 9, 'G': 3}
```

Comment: Should the title be "Why does my dictionary **not** change outside of the function?

Answer (score 2):

you are not updating `my_dct`, you are just passing it to the function, processing it and that's it. original `my_dct` remains unaffected.

to get the desired output do

`my_dct=remove_0(my_dct)`

Answer (score 2):

```
my_dct = {"A" : 0,
    "B" : 1,
    "C" : 4,
    "D" : 0,
    "E" : 0,
    "Z" : 9,
    "F" : 0,
    "G" : 3,
   }

def remove_0(dct):
    dct = {key:val for key, val in dct.items() if val != 0}
    print(dct)
    return dct

print(my_dct)
update = remove_0(my_dct)
print(update)
```

Comment: The downside to this approach is that you are replicating an entire dictionary just to replace an existing one. This isn't a big deal with small dictionaries, however much larger data will have a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value is not assigned. Just use:

```
my_dct = remove_0(my_dct)
```

Comment: While this works, the downside is that you are creating a whole new dictionary by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse not. A function runs its code block on the given argument(here your outside dict) and gives the result but it doesnot change it as in the function you are creating a new dict object (dct) and that object is actually returned not the older dict.

```
my_dct = {"A" : 0,
        "B" : 1,
        "C" : 4,
        "D" : 0,
        "E" : 0,
        "Z" : 9,
        "F" : 0,
        "G" : 3,
       }

def remove_0(dct):
    dct = {key:val for key, val in dct.items() if val != 0}
    print(dct)
    return dct

print(my_dct)
new_dict = remove_0(my_dct)
print(new_dct)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `remove_0` function, the line `dct = {key:val for key, val in dct.items() if val != 0}` is making a copy of the dict with some changes. To change the dict, you need to do:

```py
def remove_0(dct):
    for key, value in list(dct.values()): # the list acts as some kind of copy
        if value == 0:
            del dct[key]
    print(dct) # IMO this should be outside the function
    # there's no need to return a value since the function mutates the dict in place

print(my_dct)
remove_0(my_dct)
print(my_dct)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a new dict inside of the function with the line `dct = {key:val for key, val in dct.items() if val != 0}` dct will update the variable pointer and not the dict it was pointed to. If you were to want to update the dict itself, you'd have to iterate through and remove the elements something like this:

You have to make the list of keys because you can't modify the dict while iterating through it directly.

```
my_dct = {"A" : 0,
        "B" : 1,
        "C" : 4,
        "D" : 0,
        "E" : 0,
        "Z" : 9,
        "F" : 0,
        "G" : 3,
       }

def remove_0(dct):
    for i in list(dct.keys()):
        if dct[i] == 0:
            del dct[i]
    print(dct)
    return dct

print(my_dct)
remove_0(my_dct)
print(my_dct)
```

Answer (score -1):

the first thing you should note is that your input is a dictionary and dictionaries are not immutable.
the second is that there are many differences between a=b and  a=1, b=1 both have one thing but in the first case, a and b are one place in the memory so if you change anyone the other changes too. about functions the input that you assume for the computer (here, dct) and what you really insert (my_dct) are just like a=b.
see this :

```
my_dct = [1,3,4,7]
def remove_0(dct):    
    dct[0]="najme" 
    print (dct)
 print(my_dct)
 remove_0(my_dct) 
 print(my_dct)
```

Comment: out put :[1, 3, 4, 7]
['najme', 3, 4, 7]
['najme', 3, 4, 7]

Comment: This uses a list instead of a dictionary, however.

Comment: yes, we know that functions basically change their inputs once they come out but in this case, the reason it didn't change is "because it is a dictionary". and this has a priority on function action.

Comment: Your answer shows how to change an element in a `list` passed to a function. However, the question is how to delete an element from a *dictionary* passed to a function. Making it a `list` changes the parameters of the question. The reason it didn't change wasn't "because it is a dictionary" it is because the code made a copy of the dictionary returned the new dictionary and the code never used the new dictionary either by replacing the original with the new `dict` or by deleting elements in the original.